# Group by date and calculate

Tags: crystal-reports

For each account I need to subtract the earliest amount from the most recent amount.

Input

```
 - ACCOUNT      DATE      AMOUNT
 - 123        7/18/2017      500
 - 456        7/18/2017      450
 - 123        7/17/2017      300
 - 456        7/17/2017      200
```

Desired output:

```
 - 123  7/17/2017  7/18/2017 200
 - 456  7/17/2017  7/18/2017 250
```

I've tried grouping by max and min dates, but it wasn't helpful. And I don't have much flexibility in regards to the sort of the input. How can I arrange the data properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would do it:

- Group by `Account` in ascending order.
- Inside that group, Group by `Date` in ascending order.
- Suppress all Group Headers/Footers and Details Section *except for Account Group's Footer*. This is where you will place all the fields you want to display.

---

- Use 2 Shared Variables, `FirstDate` and `FirstAmount`. Set these up to store the first `Date` and `Amount` values that appear in each Account Group. (Use a Running Total that resets when this group changes. When it equals 1, fill the variables.)
- In Account's Group Footer, make two formula fields:

  1. Displays `FirstDate & "  " & Date`
  2. Displays `Amount - FirstAmount`

Comment: Thank you so much - I think this will work.   Will let you know.  Much appreciated.